# On click button event is not triggered in AngluarJS

Tags: angularjs

In my AngularJS app, I want to pass input field's value to controller when button is clicked. What I am doing for that is posted below but it's not working. So please guide what is the issue?

**index.html**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchKey">
<button type="button" ng-click="loadSearch(searchKey)">Search</button>
```

**myCtrl.js**

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    function loadSearch(key) {
        alert(key);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below approach.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
       this.loadSearch = function(key) {
          alert(key);
       }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller='MyController as ctrl' ng-app="myApp">
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchKey">
    <button type="button" ng-click="ctrl.loadSearch(searchKey)">Search</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> AngularJS creates a two way data-binding between the controller and the view. To enable both way binding, you would have to utilise `$scope`
>
> `$scope` is a built-in object and contains application data and
>   methods. You can create properties to a $scope object inside a
>   controller function and assign a value or function to it. The $scope
>   is glue between a controller and view (HTML).

In your example, the `loadSearch` method is not associated with a `$scope`, hence it is not available in the view. To fix this, `$scope.loadSearch` is the correct way.

Moreover, you need not pass the `searchkey` to the function as it is associated with the `ng-model` and available in the scope of the controller. You can easily `alert($scope.searchKey)` in the controller.

See the code snippet below for your reference.

```js
angular.module("app", []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.loadSearch = function() {
    alert($scope.searchKey);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="searchKey">
  <button type="button" ng-click="loadSearch()">Search</button>
</body>
```